# Backbone.Model.save does not set my model with the server response

Tags: backbone.js

I'm calling 'save' on my model and returning the new model as json in my PHP backend.  When I step through the Backbone.Model.save method, I can see that it successfully gets the server response and then sets the model (in the options.success closure below).  But when the execution is returned to my click handler, the model has the old properties (ie. the id is not set).  What could be happening?

Here is my click handler:

```
addButtonClick: function(e) {
  var data = $(e.target).closest('form').serializeObject();
  var p = new Domain.Page; // this extends Backbone.Model
  p.set(data);
  p.save();
  // ****
  // **** AFTER p.save, the model p still has the OLD ATTRIBUTES... why??
  // ****
  return false;
}
```

Here is Backbone's save method:

```
// Set a hash of model attributes, and sync the model to the server.
// If the server returns an attributes hash that differs, the model's
// state will be `set` again.
save : function(attrs, options) {
  options || (options = {});
  if (attrs && !this.set(attrs, options)) return false;
  var model = this;
  var success = options.success;
  options.success = function(resp, status, xhr) {
    // ****
    // **** NEXT LINE SUCCESSFULLY SETS THE MODEL WITH THE SERVER RESPONSE
    // ****
    if (!model.set(model.parse(resp, xhr), options)) return false;
    if (success) success(model, resp, xhr);
  };
  options.error = wrapError(options.error, model, options);
  var method = this.isNew() ? 'create' : 'update';
  return (this.sync || Backbone.sync).call(this, method, this, options);
},
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `save` method is asynchronous.  In other words, the `model.set` call inside `save` happens after the server has responded.

You are asking why the values are the same immediately after `save` is called.  The answer is: at that point in time, the response has not been received by your code yet.  The callback hasn't been called.  `model.set` hasn't been called.

When you continue on and the event loop gets the response from the server (this may be a fraction of a second, it may be several seconds) later, your values will get set.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  But, I'm pretty sure that is not what is going on.  I'm using the Chrome's debugger and so I step over the p.save statement, then in the console I check p.get('title').  Whether I run p.get('title') 1 second after or 60 seconds after, it still has the old attributes.  I'm pretty sure I'm making a dumb mistake somewhere, perhaps something related to scope.  Also, note that the model actually IS getting set properly in the options.success closure in Backbone.Model.save.  At the end of the options.success closure, I check model.get('title') at it's got the new value OK.

Comment: Well, your first code block had a comment immediately after `save`.  I can say with 100% certainty that your values would not be set yet at that point.  But you are saying that after the `set` call is made, the values are set but the reference you are checking hasn't changed.  You must be holding on to the wrong reference.

Comment: Also check the server's response. Backbone expects a JSON like {attribute1: value1,attribute2: value2}

Comment: Yes, I think you're correct in saying that I'm holding onto the wrong reference, but I can't see where it switches.  In my click handler I have 'p', which is an instance of Backbone.Model, then I call p.save which stores 'this' into 'model', then Backbone.sync is called which will call options.success and in there, model gets correctly 'set'.  It really seems like 'model' and 'this' are the same.  Very weird... I'll have to keep looking.  Thanks so much for your input.

Comment: Take a look at the cid on the model. It is supposed to be unique per execution. In other words, if you have two different references, you should see two different cids. Just for a test, in your debugger, set window.saved_model = model inside the callback. Then, p === window.saved_model should be true if you indeed have the same reference. If you do have the same reference but the attributes are not the same, then something must be changing your values (shock!). I'd just step-over in the debugger, checking the values of your model attributes until you see something change them back.

Comment: Yes, the cids are the same and the objects are equal using ===, I've posted what I think the answer is below.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out what was wrong here.  And Brian you were right to say it had something to do with the async nature of the Backbone.save call.  The thing is that I was using the DEBUGGER.  This stops all execution.  I actually don't really understand how an async call works under the hood, perhaps with threads?  I assumed that after I stepped over the call to 'save' and then waited a sec, then the async part (whatever that is) of the 'save' call would execute in the background.  But this is not the case.  The debugger halts everything.  So the options.success closure within 'save' always gets called sometime after stepping over 'save'.  In short, this whole thing is due to me not understanding javascript and javascript debugging properly.

Comment: Yes.  Absolutely.  This is what I was trying to say :)  You get one thread and an even loop.  The request gets made and when you return execution (after debugging) the browser runs the event loop.  If you have registered a callback, it will call you from the event loop.  Since you register a callback with Backbone who registers a callback with jQuery who registers a callback with the browser, you will eventually get called.  But since there is only 1 thread, if you are in the debugger, all execution has stopped.  The event loop doesn't run and you don't get called back.

Comment: In other words, if you stop your debugger in the place you are suggesting in the first block, your callback won't get called until you release control from the debugger.  This is the way every asynchronous environment I have worked in works.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks so much for your input!  I now understand a crucial piece of information!

Comment: Glad to help :)  (And make sure to mark my answer as correct, if you feel like it is)

Comment: Right, I'd love to do that, but it seems I can't yet as I don't have enough reputation yet.  Shoot!

Comment: There you go!  More reputation :)